# delete array value and then compact

Tags: php, arrays

I want to delete a value of a numbered index's array, and then compact the array so the left index is not empty. This is my code but i'd like to know if there is an array method which do that

```
for ($j = 30; $j < count($a); $j++) {
    if ($j+1 < count($a)) {
        $a[$j] = $a[$j+1];
    }
}
array_pop($a);
```

So this code remove the value of index 30 of the array and compact the array. 
I could use unset(a[30]) but that left me with an array with no index 30. And I can't iterate correctly that array.

Comment: That looks more like Javascript.

Comment: sorry i made a mistak. edited

Comment: oh, haha, these both languages differences make me crazy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate the array using `foreach` however to answer the index question:

```
unset($a[30]);
$a = array_values($a);
```

You might also use:

```
array_splice($a, 30, 1);
```

Comment: That was i was looking for: array_values

Comment: much simpler the better